# Two strings in the same row

Tags: javascript, html

I have two strings and want them in the same row.

.JS file example:

```
var block1 = document.createElement('div');

var title_1 = document.createElement('h3');
var title = document.createElement('a');
title.textContent = "This is test1";
title.setAttribute("role", "button");
title.href = '';
title.onclick = function () {
  var url = 'https://test.com';
  window.open(url, '_blank');
  }
title_outer.append(title);
block1.appendChild(title_1);

var title_2 = document.createElement('h3');
title_2.textContent = "This is test2";
block1.appendChild(title_2);
```

**Output is:**

> *This is test1*
>   *This is test2*

**The output I want:**

> *This is test1 This is test2*

The output should be on the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `h3` elements have `block` as their default css `display` property value. This causes them to be full-width by default (so that any elements after them are visually "pushed" to the "new-line"). If you really want the `h3` elements to be displayed next to each other (which is quite unorthodox), you could set their `display` value to `inline` or `inline-block`. You could do it with javascript like this:

```
var title_1 = document.createElement('h3');  
title_1.style.display = "inline-block";  // or "inline"
```

Alternatively, a better practice for displaying texts next to each other would be to use elements which have a "non-block" display by default. The simplest example would be the `span` element.

If you would like to have one `h3` element with two texts where first text also acts like a link, I would suggest aiming for this structure instead of having two `h3` elements:

```
<h3>
  <a> First Text </a>
  <span> Second Text </span>
</h3>
```

This way, you will not have to tweak the css at all.

Comment: This was helpful. Solved my problem. My last question would be how can I separate the two strings now that they are in the same line like First text (Second Text) or may be a space between two strings.

Comment: You could simply define the second text with a space in front: `let string2 = document.createElement('span');
 string2.textContent=" String 2";`

Comment: Alternative approach would be to define a `&nbsp;` - non-breaking space element and put it between the two texts. You could create it like this: `document.createTextNode("\u00A0");`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new element why not append new value to the already created element.

Change code from

```
var title_2 = document.createElement('h3');
title_2.textContent = "This is test2";
block1.appendChild(title_2);
```

to

```
title.textContent = title.textContent + " This is test2";
```

Does this help?

Comment: But the hyperlink for the first textContent will also be on the second textContent. I want the href only for the title1 and not title2. That is why 2 different blocks.

Comment: I see I didn't understand that part of the question. Try the css approach then :)

Answer (score 1):

You are appending two `h3` elements that they normally get into different blocks. You must append the second title to the current text content instead.

change this

```js
var title_2 = document.createElement('h3');
title_2.textContent = "This is test2";
block1.appendChild(title_2);
```

to this

```js
title.textContent = title.textContent + " This is test2";
```

Comment: But the hyperlink for the first textContent will also be on the second textContent. I want the href only for the title1 and not title2. That is why 2 different blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly an issue with the CSS. Your `h3` tag may have a `display:block;` property. Change both the tags `a` and `h3` to `span` and see if both the text lie in single line.

If changing to `span` works, you have to adjust your CSS to have both the tags have `display:inline-block;`

Comment: This worked but the inline-block creates uneven spacing between the element above and below the output. Is there a CSS way where I can use display: inline and have equal spacing? Also, how can I have space between two textContent now that they are in the same row? Can I do something like This is test1 (this is test2)?

Comment: Now you know, your JS code is fine and it's CSS that needs tweek. Set the parent `div` to have properties `display:flex;align-items:center`. That's the flexbox way of doing it.